# Extracting year/age from varied input date formats

Tags: php, regex

I have input strings which contain "ages" of people in various formats like this:

```
Input           What it means
28/          -> 28 years
5.4.83       -> 2011-1983 = 28 years
june'82      -> 2011-1982 = 27 years
21.6.83 /    -> 2011-1983 = 28 years
oct'79 /164  -> 2011-1979 = 32 years
17-1-84 2
31.08.82 6
21.10.80/5
(MAR 83.5
JAN 1987
31,
25 year
25 years
31year       -> 31 years
31years       -> 31 years
```

I need to make appropriate regexs which calcuate the age of the person. Subtracting the birthyear from 2011 is good enough.

I am using the following which is "good enough", but am wondering if I can make it better?

```
preg_match_all("/[^0-8](\d{2})[\/;\. ]/", $row[text], $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Comment: You realise that it'd be so much easier to ask for their date of birth..?

Comment: @David - tell me about it... :P But I'm doing some analysis of some textual data extracted from newspapers...

Comment: /[^0-8](\d{2})[\/;\.\s]/s - just for case of tab ended line or endline just after two digits year

Comment: Hmm - @Jan - on my test data, i get exactly the same filtered output with your regex... but thanks for the input anyway!

Comment: One kind of question that sould *not* be asked. **your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers** (see FAQ)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest handling the two cases (dates and ages) differently.
If you know the ages will be under x and the years over y, then you should filter the matches accordingly.

For ages, the regexp could be: `/(<![.'-])(\d\d)(?:/|,|$|\s*year)/`

For years : `/[.- ](?:19)?(\d\d)\b(?!\syear|,)/`

This is untested. Feel free to adapt it to your data.